# How to register a variable when using loop with stat module?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

How to register a variable when using loop with stat module?

I am working on a project where I wish to run comparisons against the known value of a collection of files (checksum), which I will then take action if a change is detected (EG: notify someone, have not written this part yet).
If this were purely a CLI matter, I would have this sorted with some easy SH scripting.
That said, I have Ansible (2.7.5) available within my ENV and am keen to use it!

In reading the vendor documents, using the [stat](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/stat_module.html) module felt the "Ansible way" to go on this one.
Currently just *NIX servers (Linux, Solaris, and possibly AIX) are in scope, but eventually this might also apply to Windows, where I expect I would use [win_stat](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/win_stat_module.html) instead with suitable parameters.

At present I plan to dump the results of the scan to a file (EG: CSV), which I would then iterate / match against, for the purposes of a comparison (to detect if a file has been somehow changed).
This is another part I have not written yet (the read a file and compare portions), but expect to hit those once I get this present matter sorted.

My current challenge, is that I can get "one-off" stat checks to work fine.
However, I expect to be targeting a whole directory worth of files, and thus want to presumably:

- "discover" the contents of the target directory, and retain this in memory
- iterate (`loop`) through the list in memory

  - performing a stat check upon each file
  - retaining the `checksum` of each file
  - building some sort of dict or list?
- write the collective results (or one line at a time) out to a log file of sorts (CSV.log: file_path,file_checksum)

I would welcome your feedback on what I might be missing (aside from some hair at this point)?

I have tried a few different approaches to looping within the playbook (`loop`, `with_items`, etc.), however the challenge remains the same.
The `stat` loop runs fine, but the trailing `register` statement fails to commit the output to memory (resulting in a variety of "undefined variable" errors).

Am I somehow missing something in my loop definition?
Looking at the vendor docs on "[Using register with a loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#using-register-with-a-loop)", it would appear I am doing this correctly (in my view anyway).

## Simple "target files" I am checking against within a directory.

```
/tmp/app/targets/file1.txt

Some text.

/tmp/app/targets/file2.cfg

cluster=0
cluster_id=app_pool_00

/tmp/app/targets/file3.sh

#!/bin/sh

printf "Hello world\n"

exit 0
```

## My prototyping playbook as it exists currently.

```
---

- name: check file integrity

  hosts: localhost
  become: no

  vars:
    TARGET: /tmp/app/targets
    LOG: /tmp/app/archive/scan_results.log

  tasks:

    - name: discover target files

      find:
        paths: "{{ TARGET }}"
        recurse: yes
        file_type: file

      register: TARGET_FILES

    - name: scan target

      stat:
        path: "{{ item.path }}"
        get_checksum: yes

      loop: "{{ TARGET_FILES.files }}"
      register: TARGET_RESULTS

    - name: DEBUG

      debug:
        var: "{{ TARGET_RESULTS }}"

    - name: write findings to log

      copy:
        content: "{{ TARGET_RESULTS.stat.path }},{{ TARGET_RESULTS.stat.checksum }}"
        dest: "{{ LOG }}"

...
```

## My "one-off" playbook that worked.

```
---
- name: check file integrity

  hosts: localhost
  become: no

  vars:
    TARGET: /tmp/app/targets/file1.txt
    LOG: /tmp/app/archive/scan_results.log

  tasks:

    - name: scan target

      stat:
        path: '{{ TARGET }}'
        checksum_algorithm: sha1
        follow: no
        get_attributes: yes
        get_checksum: yes
        get_md5: no
        get_mime: yes

      register: result

    - name: write findings to log
      copy:
        content: "{{ result.stat.path }},{{ result.stat.checksum }}"
        dest: "{{ LOG }}"

...
```

## The output was not exciting, but useful.

## Would expect to build this up with multi-line output (one line per file `stat` checked) if I could figure out how to loop / register loop output correctly.

```
/tmp/app/archive/scan_results.log
/tmp/app/targets/file1.txt,8d06cea05d408d70c59b1dbc5df3bda374d869a4
```

Comment: I would not expect your "one-off playbook that worked" to work.  If you take a second look at [those docs to which you linked](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#using-register-with-a-loop), you'll note that `result` will not have a `stat` attribute: it will have a `results` attribute, which is a list of items, each one having a `stat` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [**set_fact**](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/set_fact_module.html) module to register a variable like you want.

I don't use it in my test for you, it maybe useless in your case :

```
---
- name: check file integrity
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    TARGET: /tmp/app/targets
    LOG: /tmp/app/archive/scan_results.log
  tasks:
    - name: 'discover target files'
      find:
        paths: "{{ TARGET }}"
        recurse: yes
        file_type: file
      register: TARGET_FILES

    - debug:
        var: TARGET_FILES

    - name: 'scan target'
      stat:
        path: "{{ item.path }}"
        get_checksum: yes
      loop: "{{ TARGET_FILES.files }}"
      register: TARGET_RESULTS

    - debug:
        var: TARGET_RESULTS

    - name: 'write findings to log'
      lineinfile:
        line: "{{ item.stat.path }},{{ item.stat.checksum }}"
        path: "{{ LOG }}"
        create: yes
      loop: '{{ TARGET_RESULTS.results }}'
```

result:

```
# cat /tmp/app/archive/scan_results.log
/tmp/app/targets/file3.sh,bb4b0ffe4b5d26551785b250c38592b6f482cab4
/tmp/app/targets/file1.txt,8d06cea05d408d70c59b1dbc5df3bda374d869a4
/tmp/app/targets/file2.cfg,fb23292e06f91a0e0345f819fdee34fac8a53e59
```

Best Regards

Comment: Thank you Loïc Le Roy, for your answer.
Indeed, in this you corrected a flaw in my playbook syntax (which I had missed, due to in-correct use of the `debug: var:` definition following the `stat` loop).
Specifically I was attempting to use variable expansion, when all I needed to do was indicate the varlible name itself to use (and let Ansible handle it from there).
When I switched to the correct form, the loop results displayed as expected.
One of those "duh, I am an idiot" moments when I saw that.
Thank you also for the logging play solution, this works quite elegantly.